# Should I run catalog:images:resize on each deployment or only incidentally?

Tags: magento2, image, cli, deployment, continuous-integration

The question is simple:

Should I add `bin/magento catalog:images:resize` to our Continuous Integration script, running it on every deployment? Or is it's intent solely to run incidentally (since resized and cached images are also generated upon saving a product)?

Also: does it re-generate all images every time you run it? Or does it detect images that are already resized / cached properly and skips those?

Answer (score 1):

Only incidentally.

> Generally, product images are cached while saving the product.
>   However, the magento catalog:images:resize command enables you to
>   resize all images for display on your storefront. Situations where
>   this could be necessary might be:
>
> - **After you import products, which might have images of various sizes**
> - **If images were resized or deleted manually from cache**
>
> Each image assigned to a product must be resized in accordance with
>   image metadata defined in a module’s `view.xml` configuration file.
>   After resizing an image, its resized copy is stored in the cache
>   (/`pub/media/catalog/product/cache` directory). Magento serves
>   storefront images from cache.

Source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html#resize-catalog-images